# plot(forecast(d.ts)) omit line

Tags: r, plot, forecasting

I'm using the `forecast` package.

Suppose `d.ts` is a time series. When I use `plot(forecast(d.ts))` I get a (very nice) plot of my time series plus a forecasted line and a shaded area representing the uncertainty in the forecast. I want to omit the line (the central estimate). Obviously, I could manually remove the `Forecast` column from the `forecast(d.ts)` object and plot the remaining columns manually, but I was wondering whether there is a faster method. I can write `plot(forecast(d.ts,fan=TRUE))` but that does not omit the line (and the rest of the plot isn't what I want either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite certain that you cannot hack the forecast function in a way that the predicted values are not computed, as they are needed in order to build the confidence intervals (something along mean +- sd). But if you just want an easy way of of plotting without the predicted values, you could just set the color of the predicted values line as NA:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- StructTS(WWWusage,"level")
plot(forecast(fit),fcol=NA)
```